# Identify the Entry Widget that is being inputted by the User

Tags: python, tkinter

So I am trying to create a sudoku game with a 3x3 block with another 3x3 cells per block. I'm trying to identify the position of an entry widget that the user is using to check if its corresponding digit is the same as the solution. I can access the input by accessing **inblock[i][j]** but how can I know the position **[i][j]** when the game is running and a player is inputting into that entry widget

```
blocks = []
for i in range(3):
    row = []
    for j in range(3):
        frame = tk.Frame(puzzle, bd=1, highlightbackground='#ccddff',
                                highlightcolor='#000000', highlightthickness=2)
        frame.grid(row=i, column=j, sticky='nsew', padx=5, pady=5)
        row.append(frame)
    blocks.append(row)

inblock = []
for i in range(9):
    inrow = []
    for j in range(9):

        frm_cell = tk.Frame(blocks[i // 3][j // 3])
        frm_cell.grid(row=(i % 3), column=(j % 3), sticky='nsew', padx=5, pady=5)
        frm_cell.rowconfigure(0, minsize=50, weight=1)
        frm_cell.columnconfigure(0, minsize=50, weight=1)
        var = tk.StringVar()

        en = tk.Entry(frm_cell, relief='raised', bg='white', justify="center", textvariable=var, width=5)
        en.grid(sticky='nsew')

        if str(board[i][j]) != "0":
            en.config(state='readonly', font="bold", fg="#001a4d")
        else:
            en.config(state='normal', textvariable=tk.StringVar())

        inrow.append(en)
        var.set(str(board[i][j]))
    inblock.append(inrow)
```

Comment: When do you want to do this identification? Are you wanting to do it when they click in it? Whenever the value changes (typing a character or pressing backspace)? When you click a button?

Comment: I guess when typing a character since I want to identify the entry widget when the user is playing. Thank you for your reply